# Powershell on Windows TASK SCHEDULER

Tags: powershell

Sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand me..

I have a PowerShell script to monitor CPU usage and script executing well on PowerShell command line.
But when I schedule same script on Windows Task Scheduler, it start executing, but not respect parameters SampleInterval and MaxSamples. Like described on command below:

```
$Counter = @{
    Counter = "\Processor(_Total)\% user time", "\Processor(_Total)\% idle time", "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time", 
        "\System\Processor Queue Length", "\System\Context Switches/sec", "\System\System Calls/sec"
    SampleInterval = $intervalo
    MaxSamples = $amostra
    }

    $metrics = Get-Counter @Counter
```

Comment: In the code you've posted, `$intervalo` and `$amostra` are not defined. Please provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for reply @peter, the value off variables come from other archive..  below the full script it is too long to post here, I upload for your enjoyment http://www.filedropper.com/cpu